# When clicking on the name of the author in the author bio, my site redirects to my old url

Tags: php, wordpress

I just moved my site to a new url. Here's what I did:

1. Copied everything from old FTP account to new account
2. Changed the site url and home from phpMyAdmin
3. Exported the old database
4. Imported the database into the new site
5. edited wp-config.php

Now when I click on the author's name in the author's bio, it redirects to my old site. How do I fix this?

Comment: you need to change base URL in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change site url and home url is not enough. There are still some old url store in database.

When replacing the url, don't edit the SQL directly, because there some value stored in db in [serialized format](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/doc/serialized-data/).

Try to use tool like [Search and Replace for WordPress database](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) or [WP Migrate DB](https://tw.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to replace the url. These tools will help you to replace all the url and handle the serialized value.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to flush the new rewrite rules to overwrite some options value from the sql.

To do so, just save the permalink structure in the permalink setting page.

Answer (score -1):

> You have to replace all the old URL with new URL.

After exporting the database from phpMyAdmin open the SQL file in any text editor and use find and replace method to replace all the old URL.

Reference: [How to Move WordPress From Local Server to Live Site](http://www.webhat.in/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/)